# SetTimer doesn't work in my vb6 app

Tags: winapi, vb6, timer

I am using WinAPI, SetTimer and KillTimer in my vb6 app (it is legacy project).
SetTimer does return the right event ID but the actual callback doesn't get called at set internval.

I have

```
....
lngID = SetTimer(0, 0, 3000, AddressOf UpdateCallBack)

Public Sub UpdateCallBack(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idEvent As Long, ByVal dwTime As Long)
......
```

UpdateCallBack sometimes gets called minutes later ot even hours later.
I heard that the timer is a low priority message and it is handled when there is no other messages to handle. 
Is there a way to get the message to be processed?
If it isn't possible with SetTimer, what can I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look a t this thread: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=546633

Answer (score 1):

Is application doing anything else at the time the callback is expected?
As long as the thread is pumping messages, you should receive the callback very soon after it fires.

If the application is busy, you will need to run the message loop by calling `DoEvents`.